# How to play mp3 audio file from Resources?(using Media player not SoundPlayer)

Tags: c#, winforms

```
var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
p2.Open(Properties.Resources.myfile);
```

> Error: can not convert from System.IO.Stream to System.Uri

Comment: Check this link.. it might help u.
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/playing-audio-and-video-file-in-windows-form-application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/playing-audio-and-video-file-in-windows-form-application/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-play-media-using-a-videodrawing

Windows.Mediaplayer needs a reference position(time) and the path of your file to start with. Plus you should convert these into Uri.